# How to handle nine patch images efficiently in Android?

Tags: java, android, drawable, nine-patch, android-drawable

I am using nine patch images through out the code for setting background of LinearLayout. This layout is  being created programmatically. I am setting the nine patch like this,

```
linearlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
```

This code is being called many times inside my code. When I run profiler, it points to the usage of nine patches and it goes upto 5MB which slow downs the app while launching. Size of the nine patch is very less(~3KB). I have gone through other questions related to this. but I am unable to get a definite solution for this.

What is the best way to avoid this memory issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your own style/theme for your app and define the look of LinearLayout in it.
Then every LinearLayout you create will automaticly get the defined look from your style.

I dont know if this will reduce the memory (try it), but you do not have to give every LinearLayout the background from your code.

Hope this will help =).

Comment: Its because I have different nine patch images. Not the same one everywhere.